# Скачать изображение по URL - PHP

Tags: php, youtube

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть вот такая ссылка:

https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AKedOLS4v8kqyoR8RQ9-WQCXFhQLvAlVpnP3LYAldjwr_A=s176-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj-mo

это логотип канала на YouTube.

Вопрос, как средствами PHP скачать эту картинку?

Надеюсь на вашу помощь, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
$url = 'https://example.com/url';
$img = '/my/folder/youtube-image.png';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не работает, качает файл с размером 0.

Comment: Попробуйте, открыть url в браузере и посмотреть, что будет, возможно ссылка битая, еще у youtube есть проблема с загрузкой картинок в последнее время

Comment: В браузере открывает картинку, а выдернуть ее при помощи PHP не получается (

Comment: Прошу прощения, ввел в заблуждение,

Comment: > Попробуйте, открыть url в браузере и посмотреть, что будет, возможно ссылка битая, еще у youtube

Comment: Вы правы, на другом IP работает!

Comment: Спасибо, за правильный ответ!!!